# Jenkins adding single quotes to bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, jenkins

My shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=$1
sudo rm -rf /home/$USER/system/logs/*
exit 0
```

It's checked into cvs in a shell folder, Jenkins is configured to execute it on a Linux machine via a job with 'Execute Shell' build step:

```
bash -ex shell/clear-logs.sh myuser
```

But Jenkins is wrapping the whole sudo line in single quotes which results in my log files not been deleted (although the Jenkins job passes successfully):

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson7785398405733321556.sh
+ bash -ex shell/clear-logs.sh myuser
+ USER=myuser
+ sudo rm -rf '/home/myuser/system/logs/*'
+ exit 0
```

Any ideas why Jenkins is doing this? If I call the script from the Jenkins workspace location as the root user, then it works fine.

**EDIT:**

I have the same shell script, in different cvs modules, being executed by Jenkins on the same linux server. Have created a new job, either as freestyle or by copying an existing job where this works, but makes no difference.

Comment: Have you tried to enclose the path in double quotes yourself? Possibly this discourages Jenkins from adding single quotes and your variable is interpolated, as well.

Comment: Double quoting the path still results in Jenkins running the whole command in single quotes.

Comment: Are there any logs available to remove? If a glob fails to match any files, it is treated literally, and the trace output will quote the pattern to emphasize that fact.

Comment: Do I need to ensure that my 'jenkins' user has permissions/access to the 'myuser' location? If so, what should I check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, seemed to have resolved this by adding the 'jenkins' user to the 'myuser' group and restarting the jenkins service. If the logs directory is empty, then Jenkins console output does report the path in single quotes, as no files found. But run the job a second time where there are files, and no single quotes, files correctly deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is not doing anything with your quotation marks, such as changing double to single - you are seeing the output of `set -x`.  Try this in your shell:

```
set -x
ls "some string with spaces"
```

Output will be something like:

```
+ ls --color=auto 'some string with spaces'
```

`bash` is just showing you debug output of its interpretation and tokenization of your command.

Comment: This isn't at all what was being asked

Comment: He is explaining where the single quotes are coming from, telling that it's Bash itself that adds them when echoing arguments with spaces. But indeed this is not the whole story. In his case he was expecting Bash to do glob expansion instead of considering the last `sudo` parameter as a literal.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the permissions of `/home/$USER/...` I got the following in the *Console Output* at first:

```
+ USER=geri
+ rm -rf '/home/geri/so-30802898/*'
rm: cannot remove ‘/home/geri/so-30802898/*’: Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

After adapting the permissions the build/deletion succeeded.